# How to show last text when maxlines exceeds?

Tags: android, android-layout

my code is

```
<TextView   
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/typing"
android:maxEms="10"
android:text="efdfjhehjejfeivfdcfdjbjbdsbdjwu"
android:maxLines="2"
android:ellipsize="start"
android:padding="8dp"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_orange_bubble"
android:textColor="@color/white"
android:textSize="15dp" />
```

I want that if lines exceeds so it with show last lines of text on first lines of text

please help 
Have spent 2-3 hours

Comment: do you have any example of what you neeD?

Comment: I want to create something like live typing as IMO messenger has

Comment: and how is it ?

Comment: if live reply's text exceeds.it is settled in scrollView.and it also show latest text not first line

Comment: imo shows the typing reply of another user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ScrollView, add the texts and always scroll the ScrollView to the bottom.

Comment: Sorry but I am newbie..Sir It will be very helpful if I can get some more info about solution

Comment: As a newbie, you should first make yourself familiar with the various Views and Layouts, the Android SDK provides. Trying to create a new messenger app from scratch is probably not the best way to start. There are much bigger obstacles there, then a ScrollView with some text in it. Better start with something simple and learn the basics first. You'll have way more fun that way.

Comment: @Ridcully You only answered how to add multiple `TextViews` to a layout and always keep the most recent one visible (albeit poorly), but did not answer the actual question of how to break the text when the number of lines exceeds the `maxLines` value and place the remaining text into a new `TextView`.

Comment: @LoungeKatt So what is your not so poor solution then?

Comment: @Ridcully Well, you would have to actually split the text first. You completely ignored that step. You have a few options, but the question doesn't specify if it should be split by words or just characters. You can set an arbitrary character limit and `split` or locate the last character and `substring`. What do you need to accomplish? These would have been good things to ask before posting a half-ass non-answer.